# How do you get the client size in a Silverlight Application?

Tags: silverlight

I want to get the size of the browser window running my Silverlight Application? I've tried the following lines, but it always returns zero!

```
public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();

    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        WorldLimits.Y = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        WorldLimits.X = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;

        gameCore = new GameCore(this);
        gameTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / 1000;

    }
```

Comment: What's your UserControl markup look like in Page.xaml?

Comment: I found the problem actually. Your suggestion to put a resize event handler did the trick. If you repost the code, I can mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: It's odd that the values aren't available except in the event handler. Hmm, if it works then that's that.

Comment: Turns out the values are available, they're just set to zero by default. I'm guessing they're set sometime after the InitializeComponent(). So all you have to do is set an event handler and you'll get the values as soon as they are actually correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you're grabbing the values in an event handler

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    App.Current.Host.Content.Resized += new EventHandler(Content_Resized);
}

void Content_Resized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    this.Width = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
    this.Height = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: This is the complete block

    public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Initialize();
            
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            WorldLimits.Y = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
            WorldLimits.X = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
            
            gameCore = new GameCore(this);
            gameTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds / 1000;
            
        }

Comment: It'd be better if you edited your original answer to reflect the new code. That's usually what we do around here. If you're used to forums SO can seem odd at first, but in practice it works much better.

Comment: If you can't read that, it does happen after the Initialize component

Comment: deleting answer, should've been in comments